# Problemas ao rodar projeto com xamarin: java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError : java/lang/Object

Tags: java, android, xamarin

Isso dá sempre quando eu tento rodar um projeto Android ou CrossPlatform. Como eu faço para resolver isso?

OBS1: Voltei a ter o problema novamente e não sei o que fazer, não tenho recurso para isto.

Comment: Provavelmente tem que importar o caminho da classe, ou algo assim.

Comment: O que eu fiz foi adicionar a JAVA_HOME e o valor que coloquei foi o path do java, que no meu caso foi esse: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131`

Comment: Não tinha percebido que a classe que não encontra é a Object. Bom, nesse caso deve ser configuração da IDE, não tenho certeza pois nunca usei essa, mals não poder ajudar

Comment: Coloca mais detalhes do erro, ou tenta pegar alguns arquivos de log para nos ajudar a te ajudar

Comment: Atualizou a variável `PATH` também? Se não, inclua: `JAVA_HOME\bin` no final dela

Comment: @IgorVenturelli, somente isso Igor? Estava fora e só vi agora o seu comment. Vou fazer isso e ver o que acontece. Já me pediram para reinstalar o java, mas acho que não adianta. Pelo que me falaram, no Java tudo deve ser setado manualmente.

Comment: Aham. Ao colocar na variável `PATH` você (e os programas) vai conseguir chamar o Java. Depois de fazer isso, no terminal/prompt de comando digite `java -version`. É para mostrar umas informações, como a versão, do Java "instalado". Se aparecer que Java não é um comando conhecido alguma coisa tá errada :(